# How to cross check a list with a txt file

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to cross check a List with a txt file and I'm not sure if I have to convert it back to a list first or something else?

```
        r = open('MyFollowers.txt', 'r')
        print(List)
        newlist = []
        newlist.append(r.read())
        num = 0
        while True:
            if List[num] in newlist:
                List.remove(List[num])
            num = num + 1
        print(List)
        r.close()
```

Don't mind the extra stuff, I'm just playing around. I just can't figure out how to check and remove from main "List".

Comment: what u r trying to do? do u want to check whether the text file contains list or not?

Comment: You break from a `while` loop unconditionally, so in any case it executes once.

Comment: Yes I’m trying to check if List element is in txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that may be a problem is the way you're reading in the text file. If you read it using the `read()` method, it will return a string with the text file contents. What you can do from there is split based on newline characters (or whatever characters are separating your followers).

```
newlist = r.read().split("\n")
```

One thing with this method is that if you have a newline character at the end, it will result in an empty string as the last element. If that is the case, remove it with `newlist.pop(-1)`

To loop through, you can use the list elements as the iterator. If the element is in the text file, just remove it.

```
for follower in List:
    if follower in newlist:
        List.remove(follower)
```